# How to inspect elements that hide upon clicking inspect

Tags: css

I'm attempting to inspect the "next month" arrow button on the **Enabled/Disabled Dates** example calendar on the following site:

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I want to know what class or ID the next and previous month arrow buttons have assigned to them.

In Chrome, as soon as I attempt to inspect an element in the calendar, the div that the calendar resides in is removed. How would you force this div to stay open so that you can inspect elements of the calendar?

Thanks!

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28963272/how-can-i-inspect-html-element-that-disappears-from-dom-on-lost-focus) might help you.

Comment: My first idea was a console command to `stopPropagation` in the capturing phase on document clicks (or blurs, maybe?), once the datepicker opens, but the debugger option described in the linked question is better.

Comment: Please see my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60639050/1730846

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pause Javascript execution while the popup is open with **F8** and then right click and inspect as usual