# Keyboard shortcut to disable Javascript on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am doing some testing on a page and need to quickly disable JavaScript with a keyboard shortcut.

My problem is that the test involves popups on my screen in Chrome asking for confirmation, but if it were possible for me to disable JavaScript completely at will, then I could get past the trail of popups that come up on these test pages. Anyone knows a way? Even if it is at global level?

Comment: Found this Chrome extension that does it: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-javascript-switcher/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje?hl=en

Comment: I think this question would better fit in http://superuser.com/ Also the title is about javascript, the content about java and you should specify which system you're on.

Answer (score 7):

Check out [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38783213/3487439). You can pause JavaScript execution using the <kbd>F8</kbd> key when DevTools is open.