# Scrape website with dynamic mouseover event

Tags: python, selenium, svg, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape data which is generated dynamically from mouseover events. 
I want to capture the information from the Hash Rate Distribution chart from
https://slushpool.com/stats/?c=btc which is generated when you scroll over each circle.

The code below gets the html data from the website, and returns the table which is filled once the mouse passes over a circle. However, I have not been able to figure out how to trigger the mouseover event for each circle to fill the table.

```
from lxml import etree
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = "#Firefox web driver"
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=driver_path)
browser.get("https://slushpool.com/stats/?c=btc") 


page = browser.page_source #Get page html 
tree = etree.HTML(page) #create etree

table_Xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/table'

table =tree.xpath(table_Xpath) #get table using Xpath

print(ElementTree.tostring(table[0])) #Returns empty table. 
#Should return data from each mouseover event
```

Is there a way to trigger the mouseover event for each circle, then extract the generated data.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To trigger the mouseover event for each circle you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://slushpool.com/stats/?c=btc")
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h1//span[text()='Distribution']"))))
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h1//span[text()='Distribution']//following::div[1]/*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='g' and @class='paper']//*[name()='circle']")))
  for element in elements:
      ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Action]

Answer (score 4):

This is the `circle` locator you mean:

```
.find_element_by_css_selector('._1p0PmxVw._3GzjmWLG')
```

But it will change because mouseover effect, to be:

```
.find_element_by_css_selector('._1p0PmxVw._3GzjmWLG._1suU9Mx1')
```

[image: console]

So you need wait until the element to changed for each move.

And the most important is [how to inspect a hover element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602611/inspect-a-hover-element), then you can get the bellow:

[image: console2]

And causes the element for get data you mean to be appear:

```
xpath: //div[@class="_3jGHi0co _1zbokARu" and contains(@style,"display: block")]
```

You can use `ActionChains` to perform move the element.

Finally you can try the bellow code:

```
browser.get('https://slushpool.com/stats/?c=btc')
browser.maximize_window()

#wait all circle
elements = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '._1p0PmxVw._3GzjmWLG')))
table = browser.find_element_by_class_name('paper')

#move perform -> to table
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", table)

data = []
for circle in elements:
    #move perform -> to each circle
    ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(circle).perform()
    # wait change mouseover effect
    mouseover = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="_3jGHi0co _1zbokARu" and contains(@style,"display: block")]')))
    data.append(mouseover.text)

print(data[0])
print(data)
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

Console output:

- First data > `data[0]`

  536.9 Ph/s - 1.074 Eh/s

  User Count 2

  Average Hash Rate 546.1 Ph/s

  Group Hash Rate 1.092 Eh/s
- All data > `data`

```
[u'536.9 Ph/s - 1.074 Eh/s\nUser Count 2\nAverage Hash Rate 546.9 Ph/s\nGroup Hash Rate 1.094 Eh/s', u'67.11 Ph/s - 134.2 Ph/s\nUser Count 14\nAverage Hash Rate 91.27 Ph/s\nGroup Hash Rate 1.278 Eh/s', u'67.11 Ph/s - 134.2 Ph/s\nUser Count 14\nAverage Hash Rate 91.27 Ph/s\nGroup Hash Rate 1.278 Eh/s', u'16.78 Ph/s - 33.55 Ph/s\nUser Count 23\nAverage Hash Rate 23.36 Ph/s\nGroup Hash Rate 537.2 Ph/s', u'8.389 Ph/s - 16.78 Ph/s\nUser Count 33\nAverage Hash Rate 11.80 Ph/s\nGroup Hash Rate 389.4 Ph/s', u'4.194 Ph/s - 8.389 Ph/s\nUser Count 67\nAverage Hash Rate 5.704 Ph/s\nGroup Hash Rate 382.2 Ph/s', u'2.097 Ph/s - 4.194 Ph/s\nUser Count 137\nAverage Hash Rate 2.959 Ph/s\nGroup Hash Rate 405.3 Ph/s', u'1.049 Ph/s - 2.097 Ph/s\nUser Count 233\nAverage Hash Rate 1.475 Ph/s\nGroup Hash Rate 343.7 Ph/s', u'1.049 Ph/s - 2.097 Ph/s\nUser Count 233\nAverage Hash Rate 1.475 Ph/s\nGroup Hash Rate 343.7 Ph/s', u'524.3 Th/s - 1.049 Ph/s\nUser Count 397\nAverage Hash Rate 731.4 Th/s\nGroup Hash Rate 290.4 Ph/s', u'262.1 Th/s - 524.3 Th/s\nUser Count 745\nAverage Hash Rate 360.3 Th/s\nGroup Hash Rate 268.4 Ph/s', u'131.1 Th/s - 262.1 Th/s\nUser Count 1479\nAverage Hash Rate 182.7 Th/s\nGroup Hash Rate 270.1 Ph/s', u'65.54 Th/s - 131.1 Th/s\nUser Count 2351\nAverage Hash Rate 92.47 Th/s\nGroup Hash Rate 217.4 Ph/s', u'32.77 Th/s - 65.54 Th/s\nUser Count 3107\nAverage Hash Rate 47.23 Th/s\nGroup Hash Rate 146.8 Ph/s', u'16.38 Th/s - 32.77 Th/s\nUser Count 3380\nAverage Hash Rate 25.24 Th/s\nGroup Hash Rate 85.30 Ph/s', u'8.192 Th/s - 16.38 Th/s\nUser Count 4276\nAverage Hash Rate 13.00 Th/s\nGroup Hash Rate 55.57 Ph/s', u'4.096 Th/s - 8.192 Th/s\nUser Count 540\nAverage Hash Rate 5.953 Th/s\nGroup Hash Rate 3.215 Ph/s', u'2.048 Th/s - 4.096 Th/s\nUser Count 284\nAverage Hash Rate 3.193 Th/s\nGroup Hash Rate 906.8 Th/s', u'1.024 Th/s - 2.048 Th/s\nUser Count 226\nAverage Hash Rate 1.368 Th/s\nGroup Hash Rate 309.1 Th/s', u'512.0 Gh/s - 1.024 Th/s\nUser Count 136\nAverage Hash Rate 774.4 Gh/s\nGroup Hash Rate 105.3 Th/s', u'256.0 Gh/s - 512.0 Gh/s\nUser Count 116\nAverage Hash Rate 401.5 Gh/s\nGroup Hash Rate 46.57 Th/s', u'128.0 Gh/s - 256.0 Gh/s\nUser Count 75\nAverage Hash Rate 186.4 Gh/s\nGroup Hash Rate 13.98 Th/s', u'64.00 Gh/s - 128.0 Gh/s\nUser Count 78\nAverage Hash Rate 96.39 Gh/s\nGroup Hash Rate 7.518 Th/s', u'32.00 Gh/s - 64.00 Gh/s\nUser Count 70\nAverage Hash Rate 45.68 Gh/s\nGroup Hash Rate 3.198 Th/s', u'16.00 Gh/s - 32.00 Gh/s\nUser Count 48\nAverage Hash Rate 23.37 Gh/s\nGroup Hash Rate 1.122 Th/s', u'8.000 Gh/s - 16.00 Gh/s\nUser Count 62\nAverage Hash Rate 11.91 Gh/s\nGroup Hash Rate 738.5 Gh/s', u'4.000 Gh/s - 8.000 Gh/s\nUser Count 153\nAverage Hash Rate 3.078 Gh/s\nGroup Hash Rate 471.0 Gh/s']
```

Comment: for showing all data you can use `pprint` try it `pprint(data)`! just import `from pprint import pprint`... have fun!