# Using selenium and python to extract data when it pops up after mouse hover

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi guys this is my first question. I am trying to extract data from a website. But the problem is, it only appears when I hover my mouse over it. the website to the data is http://insideairbnb.com/melbourne/ . I want to extract the occupancy rate for each listing from the panel that pops up when I hover my mouse pointer over the points on the map. I am trying to use @frianH code from this stackoverflow post [Scrape website with dynamic mouseover event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901045/scrape-website-with-dynamic-mouseover-event). I am a newbie in data extraction using selenium. I have knowledge about bs4 package. I havent been successful in finding the right xpath to complete the task. Thank you in advance. my code so far is

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path='C:\\Users\\Kunal\\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('http://insideairbnb.com/melbourne/')
browser.maximize_window()

#wait all circle
elements = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="map"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/svg')))
table = browser.find_element_by_class_name('leaflet-zoom-animated')

#move perform -> to table
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", table)

data = []
for circle in elements:
    #move perform -> to each circle
    ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(circle).perform()
    # wait change mouseover effect
    mouseover = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="neighbourhoodBoundaries"]')))
    data.append(mouseover.text)

print(data[0])
```

thanks in adnvace

Comment: I get a timeout exception because my code is not able to locate the correct element form the website element

Comment: The "Network" tab of browser development tools can show ajax requests containing the data, then you can send the request (maybe with a cookie) and get structured data. Also, data can be in scripts in debugger/sources tab. Chances are you can get things done without selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I checked out the page a bunch and it seems quite resistant to selenium's own methods, so we'll have to rely on javascript. Here's the full code-

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('http://insideairbnb.com/melbourne/')
browser.maximize_window()

# Set up a 30 seconds webdriver wait
explicit_wait30 = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)

try:
    # Wait for all circles to load
    circles = explicit_wait30.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'svg.leaflet-zoom-animated > g:nth-child(2) > circle')))
except TimeoutException:
    browser.refresh()

data = []
for circle in circles:
    # Execute mouseover on the element
    browser.execute_script("const mouseoverEvent = new Event('mouseover');arguments[0].dispatchEvent(mouseoverEvent)", circle)
    # Wait for the data to appear
    listing = explicit_wait30.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#listingHover')))
    # listing now contains the full element list - you can parse this yourself and add the necessary data to `data`
    .......
    # Close the listing
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", listing.find_element_by_tag_name('button'))
```

I'm also using css selectors instead of XPATH. Here's how the flow works-

```py
circles = explicit_wait30.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'svg.leaflet-zoom-animated > g:nth-child(2) > circle')))
```

This waits until all the circles are present and extracts them into `circles`.

Do keep in mind that the page is very slow to load the circles, so I've set up a `try/except` block to refresh the page automatically if it doesn't load within 30 seconds. Feel free to change this however you want

Now we have to loop through all the circles-

```py
for circle in circles:
```

Next is simulating a `mouseover` event on the circle, we'll be using javascript to do this

This is what the javascript will look like (note that `circle` refers to the element we will pass from selenium)

```js
const mouseoverEvent = new Event('mouseover');
circle.dispatchEvent(mouseoverEvent)
```

This is how the script is executed through selenium-

```py
browser.execute_script("const mouseoverEvent = new Event('mouseover');arguments[0].dispatchEvent(mouseoverEvent)", circle)
```

Now we have to wait for the listing to appear-

```py
listing = explicit_wait30.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#listingHover')))
```

Now, you've `listing` which is an element that also contains many other elements, you can now extract each element however you want pretty easily and store them inside `data`.

If you do not care about extracting each element differently, simply doing `.text` on `listing` will result in something like this-

```py
'Tanya\n(No other listings)\n23127829\nSerene room for a single person or a couple.\nGreater Dandenong\nPrivate room\n$37 income/month (est.)\n$46 /night\n4 night minimum\n10 nights/year (est.)\n2.7% occupancy rate (est.)\n0.1 reviews/month\n1 reviews\nlast: 20/02/2018\nLOW availability\n0 days/year (0%)\nclick listing on map to "pin" details'
```

That's it, then you can append the result into `data` and you're done!

Comment: @KunalDhotre did you put `listing.text` before the close?