# How to webscrape leaflet maps polygons using Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, leaflet

This post is quite similar to this one: [Using selenium and python to extract data when it pops up after mouse hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62469332/using-selenium-and-python-to-extract-data-when-it-pops-up-after-mouse-hover)

But I was unable to find the answer I sought.

Im trying to webscrape a leaflet map very similar to this one: https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/, ideally I'll like to download all the information appearing after moving the mouse over the polygones:

Original post looped over every circle element,  I'll like to do the same over every polygon.

Code trials:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome
driver.get("https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/")
timeout = 1000

explicit_wait30 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
try:
    # Wait for all circles to load
    poli = explicit_wait30.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.leaflet-interactive')))
except TimeoutException:
    driver.refresh()


data = []
i=1
for circle in poli:
    i+=1
    # Execute mouseover on the element
    driver.execute_script("const mouseoverEvent = new Event('mouseover');arguments[0].dispatchEvent(mouseoverEvent)", poli)
    # Wait for the data to appear
    listing = explicit_wait30.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#listingHover')))
    data.append(listing.text)
    # Close the listing
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", listing.find_element_by_tag_name('button'))
    print(i)
    if i>15 : 
        break
```

I get error :

```
JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: arguments[0].dispatchEvent is not a function
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)
```

Seems like "leaflet-interactive" elements don't have events type mouse over, how can I reproduce human action of moving mouse over the polygons?

Comment: I'm pretty sure WebDriverWait doesn't return a list of all the elements. All it does is just block until all elements are found. To find the actual elements, you're probably going to have to use find_elements_by_css_selector. Try this first, and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

To webscrape the leaflet map and extract all the information appearing after moving the mouse over the polygons, as the desired elements are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *visibility_of_element_located*.
- You can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  driver.get('https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/')
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='Interactive Choropleth Map']"))))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src='example.html']")))
  elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("svg.leaflet-zoom-animated>g path")
  for element in elements:
      ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
      print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='info leaflet-control']"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  US Population Density
  Alabama
  94.65 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  Hover over a state
  US Population Density
  Arizona
  57.05 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  Arkansas
  56.43 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  California
  241.7 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  Colorado
  49.33 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  Connecticut
  739.1 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  Delaware
  464.3 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  Maryland
  596.3 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  Hover over a state
  US Population Density
  Georgia
  169.5 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  Hover over a state
  US Population Density
  Montana
  6.858 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  Illinois
  231.5 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  Indiana
  181.7 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  Iowa
  54.81 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  Kansas
  35.09 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  Kentucky
  110 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  Mississippi
  63.5 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  Maine
  43.04 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  Virginia
  204.5 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  Massachusetts
  840.2 people / mi2
  US Population Density
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making it flacky, overhead and lengthy execution, just grab the url where all the data is avail and parse it.

```
Url = 'https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/us-states.js'

response = requests.get(Url)

json_data = json.loads(response.text.split("=")[1].replace(';',''))

prop = jsonpath.jsonpath(json_data,"$.features[*].properties")
print(prop)
```

Imports needed -

```
import requests
import json
import jsonpath
```

**Output:-**

```
[{'name': 'Alabama', 'density': 94.65}, {'name': 'Alaska', 'density': 1.264}, {'name': 'Arizona', 'density': 57.05}, {'name': 'Arkansas', 'density': 56.43}, {'name': 'California', 'density': 241.7}, {'name': 'Colorado', 'density': 49.33}, {'name': 'Connecticut', 'density': 739.1}, {'name': 'Delaware', 'density': 464.3}, {'name': 'District of Columbia', 'density': 10065}, {'name': 'Florida', 'density': 353.4}, {'name': 'Georgia', 'density': 169.5}, {'name': 'Hawaii', 'density': 214.1}, {'name': 'Idaho', 'density': 19.15}, {'name': 'Illinois', 'density': 231.5}, {'name': 
'Indiana', 'density': 181.7}, {'name': 'Iowa', 'density': 54.81}, {'name': 'Kansas', 'density': 35.09}, {'name': 'Kentucky', 'density': 110}, {'name': 'Louisiana', 'density': 105}, {'name': 'Maine', 'density': 43.04}, {'name': 'Maryland', 'density': 596.3}, {'name': 'Massachusetts', 'density': 840.2}, {'name': 'Michigan', 'density': 173.9}, {'name': 'Minnesota', 'density': 67.14}, {'name': 'Mississippi', 'density': 63.5}, {'name': 'Missouri', 'density': 87.26}, {'name': 'Montana', 'density': 6.858}, {'name': 'Nebraska', 'density': 23.97}, {'name': 'Nevada', 'density': 24.8}, {'name': 'New Hampshire', 'density': 147}, {'name': 'New Jersey', 'density': 1189}, {'name': 'New Mexico', 'density': 17.16}, {'name': 'New York', 'density': 412.3}, {'name': 'North Carolina', 'density': 198.2}, {'name': 'North Dakota', 'density': 9.916}, {'name': 'Ohio', 'density': 281.9}, {'name': 'Oklahoma', 'density': 55.22}, {'name': 'Oregon', 'density': 40.33}, {'name': 'Pennsylvania', 'density': 284.3}, {'name': 'Rhode Island', 'density': 1006}, {'name': 'South Carolina', 'density': 155.4}, {'name': 'South Dakota', 'density': 98.07}, {'name': 'Tennessee', 'density': 88.08}, {'name': 'Texas', 'density': 98.07}, {'name': 'Utah', 'density': 34.3}, {'name': 'Vermont', 'density': 67.73}, {'name': 'Virginia', 'density': 204.5}, {'name': 'Washington', 'density': 102.6}, {'name': 'West Virginia', 'density': 77.06}, {'name': 'Wisconsin', 'density': 105.2}, {'name': 'Wyoming', 'density': 5.851}, {'name': 'Puerto Rico', 'density': 1082}]
```