# How to click on an element which becomes visible after MouseHover

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I'm trying to select the first value of a list (北京 in this case) from the website: https://search.jd.com/Search?keyword=%E5%AE%A0%E7%89%A9%E9%A3%9F%E5%93%81&qrst=1&wq=%E5%AE%A0%E7%89%A9%E9%A3%9F%E5%93%81&stock=1&page=5&s=121&click=1

The xpath is:

```
//*[@id="ttbar-mycity"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/a
```

My code is:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='ttbar-mycity']/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/a[.= '北京']").click()
```

But it throws a "No such element exception"

this is the html:
[image]

UPDATE:
this is the full code so far (thanks DebanjanB):

```
browser.get("https://global.jd.com/")
browser.find_element_by_id("key").send_keys(mysearch)
browser.find_element_by_id("search-btn").click()
wait.until(EC.title_contains(mysearch))
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(browser, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ui-areamini-text' and @title='北京']")))).perform()
WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='dd dorpdown-layer']//div[@class='ui-areamini-content-list clearfix']/div/a"))).click()
```

It throws a TimeoutException at the line

```
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(browser, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ui-areamini-text' and @title='北京']")))).perform()
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct xpath? Did you go to the html, right-click on that element, and Copy -> Xpath?

Comment: yes, its //*[@id="ttbar-mycity"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/a

Comment: Do you get the same error if you remove the `.click()`?

Comment: Also why is there a `ul` in the xpath you use in the command?

Comment: doesn't throw an error without .click(), and also without the ul, now throws this error: ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <a href="javascript:void(0)"> could not be scrolled into view

Comment: Yes, so you don't need the `ul`. Now it seems like it's just out of view so it can't be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the first value within the *list* **北京** you need to:

- [Mouse Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901045/scrape-website-with-dynamic-mouseover-event/57903003#57903003) the element with text as **北京** inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for `visibility_of_element_located()`
- Then click on the first element inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `element_to_be_clickable()`
- You can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  browser.get('https://search.jd.com/Search?keyword=%E5%AE%A0%E7%89%A9%E9%A3%9F%E5%93%81&qrst=1&wq=%E5%AE%A0%E7%89%A9%E9%A3%9F%E5%93%81&stock=1&page=5&s=121&click=1')
  ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ui-areamini-text' and @title='北京']")))).perform()
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='dd dorpdown-layer']//div[@class='ui-areamini-content-list clearfix']/div/a"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: search_jd_com]

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion on *NoSuchElementException* in [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed and resourceful answer. I tried running the code the but the 2nd line (move to element) throws a timeout.

Comment: @GustavoMoreno Even I got _Timeoutexception_ with **5** seconds initially as the site is JS based, so I had to increase the time span to **20** seconds, now it works perfect at my end. Possibly you have to go beyond that incase of slow network.

Comment: I increased to 600 and still got a timeout...the rest of the page works very fast, is it possible that there's another issue?

Comment: @GustavoMoreno Can you just copy paste the code and execute and let me know the status without any modification, bcuz the same code works flawless at my end.

Comment: @GustavoMoreno Can you update the main question with your current code trial and the complete error stack trace please?

Comment: @GustavoMoreno That wasn't my logic sequence :) I think I was offered the landing url as `https://search.jd.com/Search?keyword=%E5%AE%A0%E7%89%A9%E9%A3%9F%E5%93%81&qrst=1&wq=%E5%AE%A0%E7%89%A9%E9%A3%9F%E5%93%81&stock=1&page=5&s=121&click=1`. Can you just copy-paste-test the code from my answer only?

Comment: yeah, I did just copy and paste it also, this is just the solution in context.

Comment: @GustavoMoreno Waiting after `get()` and waiting after `search` is different. I have to have a relook tomorrow.