# Find element using Selenium Basic for VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying automate data entry using Selenium Basic for Excel VBA.

I've been able to log in to the website via locating the necessary element selectors on the login page.

Afterwards I need to get to the Claims Entry Page (https://claims.curacel.co/#/pro/claims/new).
To do so after logging in, I must do a mouse move to a button (New Claim) that displays another button (Single Claim) to get to (https://claims.curacel.co/#/pro/claims/new) when clicked.

But while inspecting the first button to find a usable selector, VBA returns an error.

> "ELEMENT NOT FOUND"

This is the code to log in (also I've commented a few of my attempts on finding the buttons element).

```vb
Sub Curacel()

    Dim Findby As New Selenium.By

    Set WB = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
        
    WB.Start
    WB.Get "https://claims.curacel.co/#/login"
      
    'error handling, if element property on the webpage has changed e.g name of an element or i.d
    If WB.IsElementPresent(Findby.ID("input-live")) = False Then
        MsgBox "Webpage Element(s) has been changed, kindly Alert Software Developer!", vbExclamation + vbInformation, "Contact Developer"
        WB.Quit
    End If
        
    ''input password and credentials
    ''UserName
    WB.FindElementById("input-live").SendKeys "almadinacliniczaria@gmail.com"
    ''Password
    WB.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/login-component/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[2]/input").SendKeys "almadina071"
    ''loginClick
    WB.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/login-component/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[3]/button").Click
        
    ''ATTEMPTS returning ELEMENT NOT FOUND
    'WB.FindElementById("dropdownMenuButton").Click

    'WB.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/provider-app-component/dashboard-component/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/nav/div/ul/div/div[1]/div/button/span").Click
        
    'WB.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/provider-app-component/dashboard-component/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/nav/div/ul/div/div[1]/div/button/text()").Click
       
    'WB.Mouse.MoveTo (WB.FindElementByCss(".dropdown"))
        
End Sub
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<button data-v-d3dab69e="" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="btn dropdown-toggle new-claim">
                                New Claim<span data-v-d3dab69e="" class="ml-2"><em data-v-d3dab69e="" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></em></span></button> 

                                New Claim
<span data-v-d3dab69e="" class="ml-2"><em data-v-d3dab69e="" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></em></span>
<em data-v-d3dab69e="" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></em>
<::before></::before>
<em data-v-d3dab69e="" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></em>
<span data-v-d3dab69e="" class="ml-2"><em data-v-d3dab69e="" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></em></span>
<button data-v-d3dab69e="" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="btn dropdown-toggle new-claim">
                                New Claim<span data-v-d3dab69e="" class="ml-2"><em data-v-d3dab69e="" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></em></span></button>
```

Comment: Can you check if it's in any iframes or shadowroots?

Comment: Thank you, i completely omitted the possibility of the element could within a shadowRoot... however i went ahead to study some solutions proffered using SeleniumBasic for vba handling ShadowRoot elements, ( https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/vba-macros/videos/vba-scrape-websites/elements-shadow-dom/ )  this precisely, so i inspected the element, and hoped to see a shadowRoot above that hosts it but there was none. kindly login to the website if you could and inspect perhaps it's there and i'm missing it. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

To do a [*Mouse Hover*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901045/scrape-website-with-dynamic-mouseover-event/57903003#57903003) to the ***New Claim*** button that displays another button ***Single Claim*** you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
Dim actions As Selenium.actions

WebElement we = driver.FindElementByXPath("//button[@id='dropdownMenuButton' and contains(., 'New Claim')]")
WB.actions.MoveToElement(we).perform
driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@aria-labelledby='dropdownMenuButton']//a[@class='dropdown-item' and text()='Single Claim']").Click
```

Comment: Returns the "Element Not Found". it is perhaps built within a ShadowRoot As suggested by @James Z

Comment: @Israel Nopes, it isn't. Can you induce some waits before both 1) `FindElementByXPath('button')` and 2) `FindElementByXPath('div')`

Comment: Yeah i did   Application.Wait (DateAdd("s", 2, Now)) couldn't find the element still