# Selenium (Python) - NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to make a simple script that goes to the homepage of The Whiskey Exchange, clicks on the following menu item, navigates to the new page and finally grabs a screenshot.

[image: menu item]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = Options()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

search_bar = driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/nav/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/a[2]")
search_bar.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

driver.save_screenshot('./image.png')
driver.quit()
```

I've tried multiple approaches to get this to work, mainly by changing the type of finder, but with no luck. I've tried copying both XPATH and Full XPATH (directly from chrome), but that hasn't worked either. Maybe it's something to do with how the site is built, but no idea.

I'm getting the following error message:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[3]/nav/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/a[2]"}
```

First time using selenium, so the struggle is a bit real. Please help.

Comment: I don't see an element with that xpath is the screenshot you want of the searchbox of the main page cause another element pops up.

Comment: Which element are you referring by _/html/body/div[3]/nav/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/a[2]_

Comment: It's the menu item that I have circled in the picture. I copied the full xpath from Chrome Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand the *Scotch Whisky* menu you don't need to click on the item, instead you can simply [*Mouse Hover*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57903003/7429447) and grab a [screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55120087/7429447) of the [webpage](https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/) using either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/')
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='Scotch Whisky']")))).perform()
  driver.save_screenshot('./Scotch_Whisky.png')
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/')
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Scotch Whisky']")))).perform()
  driver.save_screenshot('./Scotch_Whisky.png')
  driver.quit()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Screenshot:

[image: Scotch_Whisky]

Comment: Thank you! This snippet of code got me very close, so I just added an extra step to execute a click command on the "Single Malt Whisky" sub menu item and I got the result I was after!

Answer (score 0):

CSS_SELECTOR

```
a.header-button.header-button--search.js-header-button--search
```

XPATH

```
//a[@title='Search']
```

You could simply use this css selector since I don't see an xpath like that.

Comment: I have tried the CSS Selector method, I received a new error message I'm afraid. ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: Try using webdriver wait element to be clickable.